# How to change the length of axes for 3D plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

By default the 3D space where you plot in matplotlib has a cubical shape. That is, no matter which are the ranges of the X,Y and Z values, they will always rescale to fit this cube-like space. Example:
[image]

Is there anyway to modify the length of one of these axis to get a rectangular-prism-shape to plot my data?
Something like this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnst: Can I know why my comment was deleted?

Comment: It was the link of the duplicate answer which @ImportanceOfBeingErnst shared now.

Comment: Well, it was done well after I posted my comment. I have no issues but I didn't get the point of deleting others' relevant comment.